# Provider Hosted app server error

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have a provider hosted app.
If the Web App part is on my local IIS it works fine.

Here is a chunk of my AppManifest.xml file

```
 <Properties>
      <StartPage>http://localhost/myproviderappweb/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}</StartPage>
  </Properties>
```

If I change the start page to

```
<Properties>
          <StartPage>http://mysharepoint/myproviderappweb/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}</StartPage>
      </Properties>
```

and publish the web part on the IIS where SharePoint is installed

I receive this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> ```
>  Stack Trace: 
>
>
>     [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>        TestProviderAppWeb.SharePointHighTrustContextProvider.LoadSharePointContext(HttpContextBase
> ```
>
> httpContext) +35
>              TestProviderAppWeb.SharePointContextProvider.GetSharePointContext(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) +271
>              TestProviderAppWeb.SharePointContextProvider.CheckRedirectionStatus(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, Uri& redirectUrl) +56
>              TestProviderAppWeb.Default.Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e) +95
>              System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +39
>              System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1570

What could be wrong?

**EDIT:**
The error is because Session in the following method in SharePointContext.cs is null

```
    protected override SharePointContext LoadSharePointContext(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {


            return httpContext.Session[SPContextKey] as SharePointHighTrustContext;
        }
```

EDIT2:
What I have found out is that if I move the web app into a new IIS Web Application, which is not in my Sharepoint it works. It's not the ideal solution for me as I would like all in my SharePoint Web Application but I cannot find what's wrong.

Comment: At the bottom of the file __SharePointContext.cs__ there should be a `LoadSharePointContext`, one for each "type", that is probably using `httpContext.Session`, is this session null?

Comment: Hello eirikb I've edited with what I have at the bottom. How can I check if it's null?It's on the server.

Comment: Not sure what is the best approach, perhaps something simple as logging to a file? NLog or simply `System.IO.File.AppendAllText` or similar. If this is null then there is something funky about the session on your deployed site. Does it have Windows auth enabled?

Comment: Yes erikb, Windows auth is the only enabled. I try with the log and let you know. I've deployed, the web app publishing on file system and copying on a virtual directory. I then put Windows auth enabled.

Comment: Hello eirikb I've checked that httpContext.Session is null as you wrote. Is there something you could suggest that I do?

Comment: Is that not the thing with provider hosted apps, that they should run outside of the SharePoint web apps?

Comment: Did u got solution for this, as I am also having similar issue.

Comment: #Amit sorry, I haven't.